# Load certain images only when a certain CSS file is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, random

I currently have 1 html file and 3 CSS files. Each CSS file represents 3 different themes that basically represent 3 different colours i.e. 1 red, 1 blue and 1 yellow.

I am randomly loading one of those 3 CSS files on page refresh so every time you refresh the page you get a different coloured theme for the page. I am doing this using PHP and works fine. My code to do this is as follows:

```
<link href="css/colours/<?php echo mt_rand(1, 3); ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

**My question is** how do I pair up inline images with the right stylesheet so that when you hit refresh the user sees the correct images for that theme?

Each CSS file will use 4 different images and they must correlate to the right colour, so something like this:

- the **red** stylesheet must only use image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg
  and image4.jpg
- the **blue** stylesheet must only use image5.jpg,
  image6.jpg, image7.jpg and image8.jpg
- the **yellow** stylesheet must only use image9.jpg, image10.jpg, image11.jpg and image12.jpg

**EDIT**
I cannot use background images because its a responsive website and these image are centered perfectly on screen.

Comment: Put those images in your stylesheet maybe? If you only load the red stylesheet, and it only includes images 1 2 3 and 4, then you effectively only load those images. I don't really see what the problem is...

Comment: Its a responsive website and I need certain elements to be centered perfectly on screen. Ican't afford to have the images on display to get cut off

Comment: I don't see the link between centering your image and putting a different link in a few css stylesheets. Praveen's answer might be able to help you. Close voting this question.

Comment: Use background images in `div`s with a `height` and `width`. Also, if you switch themes using a class on the `body`, e.g. `<body class="red-theme">`, then you can keep all your styling in one file. Put an `Expires` header on the CSS file and you will not have to worry about loading different CSS files all the time. The images can be put one (or several) sprites, so that they are only loaded once.

Comment: Backgrounds *can* scale:  http://tinker.io/84c6f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your images in three folder, like images-1, images-2, images-3.
Now you store your random number in a variable:

```
<?php
   $theme = mt_rand(1, 3);
?>
```

When you load the stylesheet, use the variable:

```
<link href="css/colours/<?php echo $theme; ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

When you load your image:

```
<img src="images-<?php echo $theme; ?>/image1.jpg" /> <!-- Loads image 1 in of the current theme -->
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Say you have all the images in backgrounds. So, effectively, you can have rules this way, say in `red.css`, you have:

```
.header {background: url("image1.jpg");}
```

In `blue.css`, you have:

```
.header {background: url("image5.jpg");}
```

And in `yellow.css`, you have:

```
.header {background: url("image9.jpg");}
```

This way, only when the stylesheet loads, the images are loaded.

---

Or, in case if you are putting them in HTML, you won't load them visually, but you will load in the page and keep it hidden from the view. Say this way, in `red.css` you have:

```
.header {display: none;}
.header.red {display: block;}
```

In `blue.css`, you have:

```
.header {display: none;}
.header.blue {display: block;}
```

And in `yellow.css`, you have:

```
.header {display: none;}
.header.yellow {display: block;}
```

And in your HTML, you have this:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" class="header red" />
<img src="image5.jpg" class="header blue" />
<img src="image9.jpg" class="header yellow" />
```

Comment: Forcing content to load even when it isn't being rendered is painful for people who pay by the KB (which usually includes mobile users, I don't know how NA providers continue to get away with ripping people off like this).

Comment: Agreed with you, @cimmanon as I am also a mobile internet user. :)

Comment: Not a great approach because of the extra load on the page but thanks for the detailed response nonetheless!